# Text is not updating even though I am using remember and mutableStateOf

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, compose-recomposition

I've run into a strange issue in Jetpack Compose. I am currently working on an app which shows data on a graph from an external API. I am fetching data with no problem, but **my graph didn't recompose with new values**.

After debugging, I started to question composition within my app. For debugging purposes, I created a simplest possible composable function to see if everything is working properly.

And it doesn't work at all... I tried code below in different project and everything is fine there.

```
@Composable
fun Counter() {
    val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Button(
            onClick = {
                count.value++
                Log.d("f", "Value: ${count.value}")
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked button ${count.value}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        ) {
            Text("Click me")
        }
        Text(text = "Current count: ${count.value}")
    }
}
```

I can see count value increasing in Logcat as well as in the Toast, however **the Text stubbornly  shows only 0**.

Here are the screenshots:
[from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCp8f.png)
[from the Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM9qw.png)

Here is my `build.gradle` file (Note that `compose_ui_version` is set to '1.3.1'.):

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
namespace 'com.example.airmockapiapp'
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.airmockapiapp"
    minSdk 30
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_ui_version
}
packagingOptions {
    resources {
        excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.3"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.3"

// Compose viewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1"

// Compose navigation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"

//Jetpack Compose Charts from tehras
//implementation "com.github.tehras:charts:beta-01"

// Williamchart xml charts library
//implementation 'com.diogobernardino:williamchart:3.3.0'

// Composable-Graphs from jaikeerthick github
implementation 'com.github.jaikeerthick:Composable-Graphs:v1.1'
```

}

Comment: How do you call `Counter` composable?

Comment: @Steyrix thanks for asking me, I didn't test OP's code at first before assuming a problem and doing answer, but it seems working right?, not sure whats not working

Comment: @z.y you are welcome :) Actually I think it has something to do with the onclick happening outside of composable scope, so it updates the toast and button, but does not call Text to recompose

Comment: @Steyrix I'm not sure anymore now, I tested OP's code and its working..

Comment: @z.y then you better be ready to another chat discussion :D

Comment: Hello guys, I'm calling the counter composable in onCreate, no suprises there. Indeed, code is supposed to work, and I've tested it in other project, it's the most basic Jetpack Compose staff... However, it's not working and I wonder what can cause lack of recomposition in my case.

Comment: @jakgrab what version of compose compiler and compose libs do you use? Can you provide your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @jakgrab try use `androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1'

Comment: @ConstOrVar Who would have thought that a simple material library can cause such trouble? Works now, thanks a lot!

Comment: @jakgrab absolutely agree with you. Use `bom`. Goog luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are conflicting versions of some compose libraries in your configuration. To fix that issue in your case you can manually change version of `androidx.compose.material:material` to `1.3.1`. To avoid such problems in the future, it'll be better to use [bom files](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#bom-version-mapping) - it's official recommendation.

Comment: Thanks again @ConstOrVar, I'll make sure to use them from now!

Comment: Wow!! Been stuck on a similar issue for ages and this fixes it.  The dependencies created by a new empty compose project (not material3) seem to introduce this confilct by default!

Comment: perfect, I have struggled with this error couple of days and can't find the logical reason for not working correctly, thanks a lot :)