# Issues with Compose Recomposition

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

i'm trying to use multiple screens in my app. I've defined navhost with routes. To cut long story short, my app goes from splash screen to Tasks screen which has just one text label and one button. Clicking button is supposed to update the text but its not. Following is the code for the `TaskScreen.kt`:

```
@Composable
fun TasksScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: TasksViewModel
) {
    var countClicks by remember{ mutableStateOf(0) }
    Column(){
        Text(
            text = "Task: ${countClicks}",
        )
        Button(onClick = {
            countClicks++
            Log.d("TAG", "TasksScreen() --> $countClicks")
        }) {
            Text("Click Me: $countClicks")
        }
    }
}
```

In the layout inspector I see that both the button and the text are being recomposed, but they don't actually updated the value:

[image]

Logcat window shows the countClicks being correctly updated too:

```
D  TasksScreen() --> 1
D  TasksScreen() --> 2
D  TasksScreen() --> 3
D  TasksScreen() --> 4
```

Really confused why this isn't working properly.

Comment: It works for me, not sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: @fakhir, please read [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74747747/8490194) to similar issue and check your library versions.